# Updating pyplot maker's position on tkinter button click

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

I am struggling to figure out a way to plot a graph in which values of x axis and y axis comes from two tkinter spinbox where the range of spinbox for the x axis is 125 to 8000 and y axis is -10 to 125, it plots from one point in the graph to the other when a tkinter button is pressed based on the values provided by the spinboxes.

The sample code is:

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import collections

class PlotClass():
    def __init__(self):
         fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=70,facecolor='cyan')
         ax = fig.subplots()
         ax.set_xlim(100,9000)
         ax.set_ylim(130,-10)

         x = [125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000]
         ticks = [125,250,500,"1K","2K","4K","8K"]
         xm = [750,1500,3000,6000]

         ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
         ax.set_xticks(x)
         ax.set_xticks(xm, minor=True)
         ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
         ax.set_xticklabels([""]*len(xm), minor=True)

         ax.yaxis.set_ticks([120,110,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0,-10])

         self.line2,= ax.plot([],[],'-o',markersize=15.0,mew=2)
         ax.grid(color="grey")
         ax.grid(axis="x", which='minor',color="grey", linestyle="--")
         self.canvas = canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=master)
         canvas.show()
         canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=3,rowspan=15)
         self.spin = Spinbox(master, from_=125,to=8000,command=self.action)
         self.spin.grid(column=5,row=2)

         self.spin2 = Spinbox(master, from_=-10,to=125,command=self.action)
         self.spin2.grid(column=5,row=3)

         self.button = Button(master, text="plot here",command=self.plot)
         self.button.grid(column=5,row=4)

    def linecreate(self, x=1000,y=20):
        X,Y = self.line2.get_data()
        if x in X:
            ch = list(X)
            counti = ch.count(x)
            Y[counti] = y
            print("Working")
            print(Y)
            self.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            X = np.append(X,[x])
            Y = np.append(Y,[y])
            self.line2.set_data(X,Y)
            self.canvas.draw_idle()


    def plot(self):
        self.linecreate(float(self.spin.get()),float(self.spin2.get()))

master = Tk()
plotter = PlotClass()
plotter.ok(125,10)
master.mainloop()
```

Now the problem is, it needs to check if a particular marker is already in the same x axis, it generally plots a new line to where a new value is added, but I need a way such that when the value of the x axis is 125 and it has already been plotted once to any value like 50 in the y axis, and then it went to plot 500 in x and 90 in y, and finally it again tries to plot 125 in x and 20 in y, the graph creates a marker, but I need to just redraw the old plot with the new Y value without creating a new marker.

In the above code I tried `If x in X:` to check if the x axis already have been plotted, even though I could check that but I cannot replace the Y axis value with the new value and redraw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to update the plot with `self.line2.set_data(X,Y)` in case the value already exists.

```
def linecreate(self, x=1000,y=20):
    X,Y = self.line2.get_data()
    if x in X:
        ch = list(X)
        counti = ch.index(x)
        Y[counti] = y           
    else:
        X = np.append(X,[x])
        Y = np.append(Y,[y])
    self.line2.set_data(X,Y)
    self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Actually it is not working correctly, it is often changing the wrong markers. And when I am trying to plot in the same x axis twice for the first time it is returning `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: Yep, better use `ch.index(x)`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the problem, however, I already resolved it in another way. :)